# Getting pointer to struct in list in Go

Tags: list, go

I'm trying to make a function that will look through a list (type container/list) of elevator-structs and return a pointer to the elevator that has the correct ip-address (the program is meant to control elevators on multiple computers) or nil if there is no elevator with this address.

Here is the function code:

```
func (e *ElevatorList)IPIsInList(ip string) *elevator{
    for c := e.Elevators.Front(); c != nil; c = c.Next(){
        if(c.Value.(elevator).Ip == ip){
                return c.Value.(*elevator)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I think the casting in the first return line looks kind of fishy but it's one of the few implementations that hasn't caused compiler errors. When I run the program I first get the output from other functions, and when the `IPIsInList()` function is called i get the following:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is **main.elevator, not main.elevator

runtime.panic+0xac /home/fredrik/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1254
runtime.panic(0x4937a8, 0xf84002aaf0)
assertE2Tret+0x11d /home/fredrik/go/src/pkg/runtime/iface.c:312
assertE2Tret(0x4927f8, 0x45e6d8, 0xf8400004f0, 0x7fbae00c1ed8, 0x10, ...)
runtime.assertE2T+0x50 /home/fredrik/go/src/pkg/runtime/iface.c:292
runtime.assertE2T(0x4927f8, 0x45e6d8, 0xf8400004f0, 0x28)
main.(*ElevatorList).IPIsInList+0x5b /home/fredrik/Dropbox/Programmering/go/listtest/elevatorList.go:72
main.(*ElevatorList).IPIsInList(0xf8400001c8, 0x4a806c, 0x2e3332310000000f, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
main.main+0x1f3 /home/fredrik/Dropbox/Programmering/go/listtest/main.go:53
main.main()
runtime.mainstart+0xf /home/fredrik/go/src/pkg/runtime/amd64/asm.s:78
runtime.mainstart()
runtime.goexit /home/fredrik/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:246
runtime.goexit()
----- goroutine created by -----
_rt0_amd64+0xc9 /home/fredrik/go/src/pkg/runtime/amd64/asm.s:65
```

How should this be done? I have rewritten the function many times and I think it's the use of `c.Value.(elevator)` and/or `c.Value.(*elevator)` that's causing the problem. Here are the structs for `elevator` and `Elevator_list`:

```
type elevator struct {
Ip string
OrderList [FLOORS][3]int32
Floor int32
Dir int
Ms_since_ping int32
}

type ElevatorList struct {

Elevators *list.List

}
```

The `elevator`s are added to the list with the function

```
func (e *ElevatorList) AddToList(newElevator *elevator){
e.Elevators.PushBack(&newElevator)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Obviously container/list works, but the answer to "How should this be done?" may be "don't use container/list, just use plain slices."  Here's an alternative version:

```
package main

import "fmt"

const FLOORS = 6

type elevator struct {
    Ip            string
    OrderList     [FLOORS][3]int32
    Floor         int32
    Dir           int
    Ms_since_ping int32
}

type ElevatorList []*elevator

func (list ElevatorList) IPIsInList(ip string) *elevator {
    for _, e := range list {
        if e.Ip == ip {
            return e
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (list ElevatorList) PrintAll() {
    fmt.Println(len(list), "items in list:")
    for _, e := range list {
        fmt.Println("  ", *e)
    }
}

func main() {
    var list ElevatorList
    list = append(list, &elevator{Ip: "1.1.1.1"})
    list = append(list, &elevator{Ip: "2.2.2.2"})
    list.PrintAll()
    list.PrintOne("1.1.1.1")
}

func (list ElevatorList) PrintOne(ip string) {
    if e := list.IPIsInList(ip); e == nil {
        fmt.Println(ip, "not found")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("found:", *e)
    }
}
```

Note that there was no need for ElevatorList to be a struct.  I completely tossed the AddToList method.  You might even toss IPIsInList.  Without it the method PrintOne doesn't look any more complex.

```
func (list ElevatorList) PrintOne(ip string) {
    for _, e := range list {
        if e.Ip == ip {
            fmt.Println("found:", *e)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(ip, "not found")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your add function, you are taking a *elevator and taking the address of the pointer before putting it in your list. In your retrieve function you are asserting that the type is an *elevator twice. Once in the if statement and once in the return. Both of them disagree with the true type (**elevator). Your if statement is the first one so it panics explaining that the variable is an **elevator and not an elevator:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is **main.elevator, not main.elevator
```

I would do two things. First, add *elevators to the list, not **elevators:

```
func (e *ElevatorList) AddToList(newElevator *elevator){
    e.Elevators.PushBack(newElevator)
}
```

Next, I would change the if statement so it does a type assertion to *elevator, not elevator:

```
if(*(c.Value.(*elevator)).Ip == ip){
```

Comment: Thank you. I think we are on the right track, but now it gives me     "panic: interface conversion: interface is *main.elevator, not main.elevator" When I try to add an *  like this: e.Elevators.Pushback(*newElevator), I get     "panic: interface conversion: interface is main.elevator, not *main.elevator"

Comment: You have a second error that is in your retrieval function. `if(c.Value.(elevator).Ip == ip)`. That is another type assertion that is again wrong. It is an *elevator, not an elevator.

Comment: Yes, I get an compiler error: "cannot use c.Value.(elevator) (type elevator) as type *elevator in return argument" unless I have the * there.

Comment: So you need to explicitly reference the pointer. `if(*(c.Value.(*elevator)).Ip == ip){`

Comment: OK. Now I have the add-function you proposed and the get-function uses `if(c.Value.(*elevator).Ip == ip)` and `return c.Value.(*elevator)`. The program compiles, but gives me **panic: interface conversion: interface is main.elevator, not *main.elevator** If I use `if(*(c.Value.(*elevator)).Ip == ip)` I get compiler error **invalid indirect of c.Value.(*elevator).Ip (type string)**

Comment: Sorry, I think it should be `if((*c.Value.(*elevator)).Ip == ip`. I am never good with the priority of the * operator. I normally do it as a separate step. Anyways, I do not know why it is saying that the interface is a main.elevator. I would add an ampersand where we took it away before, but that makes no sense.